# Применяется не тот класс CSS, который нужен

Tags: css

Не могу понять почему применяется внешнее правило CSS, a не внутреннее,
`<div class="Post_post__gI2Hu">` находится внутри `<div class="Profile_content__3EemM">`, но применяется класс `Profile_content__3EemM`, из-за чего аватарка растягивается на длину верхнего фонового изображения, смотрите прикрепленное изображение.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/pokrovsky-marat/pen/xxOeBZw)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну ведь очевидно же, правило

```
.Profile_content__3EemM {
  grid-area: c;
  background-color: lightpink;
}
.Profile_content__3EemM img {
  width: 700px;
}
```

объявлено после

```
.Post_post__gI2Hu img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Потому оно и главнее.